# Java- serializing non serializable objects using Xstream

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I'm trying to serialize a third-party class (which is not serializable) and I'm using xstream to do so.

At first I tried to build some class to see if it goes well and everything worked fine, But when I tried to convert the third-party instance to xml it thorws exceptions.

the code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
import vohmm.application.SimpleTagger3;

public class Tagger{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleTagger3 tagger = new SimpleTagger3(args[0]);
            XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

            String tagger_xml = xStream.toXML(tagger);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
 }
```

the exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sleepycat/je/DatabaseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2002)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.getMethod(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:164)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.getMethod(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.supportsReadObject(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:105)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.isSerializable(SerializableConverter.java:107)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.canConvert(SerializableConverter.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$1.lookupConverterForType(XStream.java:498)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:48)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1022)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1011)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:984)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:971)
    at NewDemo.main(NewDemo.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 56 more
```

Is there a resone why xstream won't work with SimpleTagger3? Is there any other way to export java object?

Comment: looking at the trace i would say you miss a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Your classloader failed to load a class named 'com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseException'.
Make sure that this class is available. Try `Class.forName("com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseException")` to test if the class is available.
If not add it to your classpath or load it with a ClassLoader.

Comment: How do I load it with ClassLoader? Where can I find that class(sleepycat)?

Comment: I found the class as a part of the 'Berkeley DB Java Edition', try to find the .jar files of this project. You can load them with `new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("<name of the jar>")}).loadClass("<full class name>")` in some cases you only need to create a new ClassLoader.